# Filling some details in a proof in Jech's $\textit{Set Theory}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

In a proof given on p. 25 of his [*Set Theory*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/WTAl997XDb4C?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVgurX8uv1AhUCmuAKHZWxBegQre8FegQIFhAG), Jech writes (added emphasis):

> By induction, let $$\begin{align*} P_0&= \emptyset,\;\;\;\;\;P_{\alpha+1} = \{\,x\in P\,:\,\forall y\, (y\,E\,x \to y \in P_\alpha)\}\\P_\alpha&= \bigcup_{\xi < \alpha} P_\xi\;\;\;\text{if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.}\end{align*}$$  Let $\theta$ be the least ordinal such that $P_{\theta + 1} = P_\theta$ (such $\theta$ exists ***by Replacement***).

Here, $P$ is a set<sup>1</sup>, and $E$ is a well-founded relation on $P$.

Here is the closest I can come to proving the existence of the $\theta$ mentioned at the end of the excerpt.

Since I find Jech's choice of notation somewhat inconvenient to my argument, I will introduce some new notation: define the function $\pi$ by $\pi(\alpha) := P_\alpha$.

Then, $\pi({\mathit Ord}) \subseteq \wp(P)$.

At this point, my thinking goes along these lines: since ${\mathit Ord}$ is a proper class (as Jech proved on p. 20), $\wp(P)$ is a set  (by Separation, p. 9), and a proper class is always "larger" than a set (something I know from folklore, though would have a hard time proving on-the-fly), some sort of "transfinite pigeon-hole principle" would ensure that there are ordinals $\gamma < \delta$ such that $\pi(\gamma) = \pi(\delta)$.  Since $\pi$ is nondecreasing, this means that $\pi(\gamma) = \pi(\gamma + 1)$.

The desired $\theta$ is the smallest element of (the well-ordered) non-empty set $$\{\eta \in (\gamma + 1)\,:\, \pi(\eta) = \pi(\eta + 1)\}.$$

Jech does not say anything about a pigeon hole principle, transfinite or otherwise, until p. 107.
In lieu of that, one could argue as follows.  Let ordinal $\beta$ be the order type of $\wp(P)$.  Then, there exists an (order) isomorphism $\varphi: \wp(P) \to \beta$.  Now consider the function given by $\varphi \; \circ (\pi\!\!↾\!\!\beta^+): \beta^+ \to \beta $, where I am using $\beta^+$ as shorthand for $\beta + 1$.  If $\pi\!\!↾\!\!\beta^+$ were strictly increasing, then $\varphi \; \circ (\pi\!\!↾\!\!\beta^+)$ would be an isomorphism from $\beta^+$ onto an initial segment of $\beta$, a contradiction.  This means that there must be ordinals $\gamma < \delta < \beta^+$ such that $\pi(\gamma) = (\pi\!\!↾\!\!\beta^+)(\gamma) = (\pi\!\!↾\!\!\beta^+)(\delta) = \pi(\delta)\;$.  $\;\square$

---

I feel very shaky about this proof.  Even if it is correct (which I am not entirely certain of), I suspect that it is overly laborious.  The reasons I think this is that (a) it strikes me as a lot of work to be glibly summarized with two words, "by Replacement"; and (much worse) (b) I don't see that the Axiom of Replacement plays such a central role in this proof, if at all.

Jech enunciates the Axiom of Replacement like this (p. 13):

> *If a class $F$ is a function, then for every set $X$, $F(X)$ is a set.*

It is true that, at the beginning of my argument, I determine that $\pi({\mathit Ord})$ must be a set, but the reasoning is not based on the Axiom of Replacement (which would not apply anyway, since ${\mathit Ord}$ is not a set), but rather on the fact that $\pi({\mathit Ord})$ is included in the set $\wp(P)$.

I conclude that there must be a *much* simpler proof of $\theta$'s existence, that does in fact rest on the Axiom of Replacement, but I cannot see it.  Could some one spell it out for me?

Also, please let me know if my proof is wrong, or if there is a way to make it less of a slog.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> More precisely, I *infer* that $P$ is a set; Jech does not say so explicitly.  He just writes "**Theorem 2.27.** *If $E$ is a well-founded relation on $P$, ...*".  Since he has defined well-founded relations only for sets, I conclude that $P$ must be a set.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the assumption that $P$ is a set is crucial, and although Jech doesn't state it explicitly in the theorem statement, it is implied by the preceding sentence.

I may be missing something as well, cause I don't see an easy way to prove $\theta$ exists here without first proving the fact that $P_\alpha$ is increasing. But after that, it goes similarly to how you imagine it... If $\theta$ didn't exist, $\alpha\mapsto P_\alpha$ would be an injective map from the ordinals into $\mathcal P(P)$, which is impossible since the ordinals are a proper class and $\mathcal P(P)$ is a set.

As for putting some rigor on the last step (and thus on the "transfinite pigeonhole principle"), note that if such an injection $f:\mathrm{Ord}\to \mathcal P (P)$ existed, then $f^{-1}: \operatorname{ran}(f)\to \mathrm{Ord}$  would be a surjective function.  Since $\operatorname{ran}(f)$ is included in $\mathcal P (P)$, it is a set.  Therefore, $f^{-1}(\operatorname{ran}(f)) = \mathrm{Ord}$ would be a set, by replacement.

Comment: Thanks!  Did you mean to write "without first proving the fact that $P_\alpha$ *cannot be (strictly)* increasing"?

Comment: @kjo No, I just meant increasing. But if we prove it is increasing and assume $\theta$ doesn’t exist, then that means it’s strictly increasing, which is what leads to a contradiction.