# Is there a simple way to extend a theorem or definition from sets to classes?

Tags: set-theory

One of the most serious difficulties I have reading Jech's [*Set Theory*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/WTAl997XDb4C?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVgurX8uv1AhUCmuAKHZWxBegQre8FegQIFhAG) is his (IMO appalling) habit of omitting whether a variable is supposed to refer to a set or to a (possibly proper) class.  Here's an entirely typical example (p. 25):

> **Theorem 2.27.** *If $E$ is a well-founded relation on $P$, ...*

It is left to the reader to somehow figure out whether $P$ is a set or a class<sup>1</sup>.

Furthermore, Jech gives one the impression that the class/set distinction is a triviality not worth fussing much over.  For example, on p. 10 he defines an *$n$-ary relation* as "a **set** of $n$-tuples," (my emphasis in **bold**).  But then, on the next page, he breezily tells us that "[i]n general, we call a **class** $R$ an $n$-ary relation if all its elements are $n$-tuples;..."  So, it turns out that—whaddyaknow!—, a relation can be a class, after all, and it is then left to the reader to sort out how much of what Jech wrote between the two different definitions of "$n$-ary relation" applies *also* to those $n$-ary relations that are proper classes.

One consequence of this seemingly cavalier attitude towards the class/set distinction is that whenever Jech applies to some unspecified variable $X$ some theorem $\mathcal{T}$ that he proved earlier for *sets*, I cannot distinguish between these two alternatives:

- since $\mathcal{T}$ is being applied to $X$, and $\mathcal{T}$ was proved for sets, it follows that $X$ must be a set;
- even though $\mathcal{T}$ was proved for sets, it is actually also true of classes, so $X$ could be a proper class.

An analogous ambiguity arises when what is being invoked in connection with the "mystery $X$" is not some previously-proved theorem $\mathcal{T}$ of sets, but rather some earlier definition $\mathcal{D}$ that referred to sets (such as the *first* definition of "$n$-ary relation" cited earlier).

**Qs:** Is there a quick ("rule-of-thumb-like") way to determine when a prior theorem $\mathcal{T}$ or prior definition $\mathcal{D}$ can be extended from sets to classes, and if so, how to do it?  Alternatively, what are the pitfalls in such translation from sets to classes?  Are there mistakes that mathematicians routinely make and that ultimately boil down to a failure to properly take into account the difference between sets and classes?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In this particular case, I concluded that $P$ had to be a set.  See the footnote in this [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4389317/13675) of mine.</sup>

Comment: I don't think Jech has *any* theorems about classes. Classes are simply an informal way to talk about formulas. But the set theory he uses has only one kind of object, sets.

Comment: This is a good question, but might not admit a snappy answer suitable for this forum. I would suggest that you  supplement Jech with a book that is more careful and pedagogical on this issue, such as Kunen’s *Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs*.